# WPF Notification Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, push-notification

I am working on a WPF project and I want to create a notification mechanism for the app. Specifically, the user can go to Settings tab, change the settings for the notifications (ex. daily at 7am or weekly every Thursday 2PM, etc.). Once the settings is set, they will see a toast notification popping up in the bottom right corner of the desktop screen. I am aware that I will need an API for this. The API is called when the notification set time comes and the notification is shown. I have been doing research about `System.Threading.Timer` and `Quartz.NET` but I didn't find anything related to WPF notification. Does anyone know any source explaining how to implement the timer and notifications that I can refer to? I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Modified question:
Just to clarify my question, what I wanted to know is how can I develop the logic so that API call is made to get notification data on a specific date/time (depending on which settings users made) and then show the result as a toast.
So, the main question is how to call API periodically even when the app is not open and running.

Comment: You can use toast notification https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp

Comment: @emoacht Toasts don't work out of the box in WPF.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. WPF does not have function to send a toast notification by default.

Comment: What operating system do your users have? Toast will work with win10 or 11. I use it in my accounting system.

Comment: If you want the task to be fired by the local computer, then you might look at task scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You can include `System.Windows.Forms` class in your project and use `NotifyIcon`. Here I have prepared a small example for you below.

```
var notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon("Icon.ico");
notifyIcon.Visible = true;
notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Title", "Message", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

If you want to make notification within the application, not the system notification, I can recommend [Notification.Wpf](https://github.com/Platonenkov/Notification.Wpf).

Management of notifications is a different matter. It depends on your requirements and your current system. Will the app always be open? Or will it manage a service you wrote during application installation? It can vary depending on a lot of questions.

Comment: So what I want to achieve is after user sets the settings for notifications (for example Weekly or Daily at a specific day/date), the notifications will popup on that date/time even if the user closed the app.

Comment: For this, you need to write a service that will run in the background of the computer. You can have a look at the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it easily with the OS's standard toast notification using [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.notifications).

Let's say you want to send a toast notification at 21:00pm today.

```cs
var time = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddHours(21));

new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddText("TIME REMINDER")
    .AddText("This is a scheduled message.")
    .Schedule(time);
```

That's it. See [Schedule a toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/scheduled-toast).